# connecting using ssh tunnel with client using remote ip and not local ip

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

i have following problem

following ssh connections work perfectly well:

hostAWin --> hostBLinux

hostBLinux --> hostCLinux

i need to enable a client sitting on hostAWin to connect to hostCLinux using ssh to hostCLinux ip

but this communication is blocked by firewall

i can't use ssh tunneling because that would be done via directing client to localhost, but i need the client to continue trying to connect to hostC's ip.

how can i do it? (if it is even possible...)

---

CLEARIFICATIONS::

i can't map the hosts file on A, because the real situation is that i have multiple machines (c,d,e,f...) all of which inaccessible by A.

and in A, i need to open multiple ssh connections (one for each of c,d,e,f...)

i wanted to simplify the issue, so i presented a single connectivity problem, when infact it is one to many. all blocked from a by corporate fw, and all accessible through b.

Answer (score 0):

If your client on hostA is connecting to hostC by name (not IP address), then you could point that hostname to 127.0.0.1 using c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts , so it uses your ssh tunnel instead of connecting directly.

For that matter, you could point hostC's DNS name to hostB's IP address, and just use the one-hop tunnel from hostB to hostC

Comment: i already thought of and ruled out this solution. while its ok if the client has only single connection, in my case the client connects to many servers, so i can't use the same ip for all. it must be unique ip for each (there is actually more than c, it is c, d, e... all blocked by fw, and accessible from b

Comment: regarding the single hop solution you proposed, not sure i followed you. what do you mean point hostC's dns name to hostB's?, what is one-hop tunnel?

Comment: What I meant was set hostC's name to hostB's IP address in hostA's network settings. Then hostA tries to connect to hostC, but actually sends the traffic to hostB, where you have an ssh tunnel that forwards the connection to hostC (but bypassing the firewall that is blocking hostA <-> hostC direct).

Answer (score 0):

at the end i was able to solve the issue by using a ui client by delight industries which enabled me to couple a local ip (127.x.y.z) to the same port to create different connections

this way i was able to link a single machine through another single machine to many different machines
so it was like this

127.0.0.1:22 -> 22:mediatorSshAccessible machine-> 22:machineC

127.0.0.2:22 -> 22:mediatorSshAccessible machine-> 22:machineD

127.0.0.3:22 -> 22:mediatorSshAccessible machine-> 22:machineE

and so on and so on...

only one question remains now.

how do i recreate this using some more standart client such as putty?
putty won' allow me even to map the local ip.
how can i do it using regular ssh commands?